# Extracting the values of elements (XML) which is in an array and put it in the message property in Camel

Tags: dom, apache-camel

As you can see the Availability Flag, BeamId is getting repeated. How do  I traverse and set the property for Availability Flag1 and so on, so that I can later fetch it with velocity template?

```
Payload:<ns2:TransportFeasibilityResponse>
<ns2:Parameters>
<ns2:AvailabilityFlag>true</ns2:AvailabilityFlag>
<ns2:SatellitedID>H1B</ns2:SatellitedID>
<ns2:BeamID>675</ns2:BeamID>
<ns2:TransportName>Earth</ns2:TransportName>
</ns2:FeasibilityParameters>
<ns2:Parameters>
<ns2:AvailabilityFlag>true</ns2:AvailabilityFlag>
<ns2:SatellitedID>J34</ns2:SatellitedID>
<ns2:BeamID>111</ns2:BeamID>
<ns2:TransportName>Jupiter</ns2:TransportName>
</ns2:Parameters>
</ns2:TransportFeasibilityResponse>
</ns2:TransportFeasibilityResponseMsg> 


Code: (Its not complete)
public static HashMap<String,String> extractNameValueToProperties(String msgBody, selectedKeyList, namelist) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = null;
        try{
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(msgBody)));
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Exception actException = new Exception( "Exception while extracting tagvalues", ex);
            throw actException;
        }

        HashMap<String,String> tagNameValueMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        // Trying to enter the TransportFeasibilityResponse element
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {                        
            Node indNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (indNode.indexOf(String name)>-1);
```

//checking for Availability flag and similar namelist

```
            dataKey = indNode.getTextContent();
            message.setProperty(selectedKeyList[k], dataKey);   
            k++;
            j++;            
            else
            {
            continue;
            }
            }


    }

Here,
I am setting these values in my route:

<setProperty propertyName="namelist">                                       
<constant>AvailabilityFlag,SatellitedID,BeamID</constant>
</setProperty>

<setProperty propertyName="selectedKeyList">                                        
<constant>AvailabilityFlag1,SatellitedID1,BeamID1,AvailabilityFlag2,SatellitedID2,BeamID2 </constant>
</setProperty>
<bean beanType="com.gdg.dgdgdg.javacodename" method="extractNameValueToProperties"/>
```

Question: Please tell me how I can parse through the repeating elements and assign it to the property?

```
Thanks
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your insight. As I needed it pretty urgent I started working on different approach. I used org.w3c.dom package (specially node list) and traversed through every node and put it in a hashmap. As I have unique keys I was able to get the values and set them in velocity template.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think you could use the [Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) pattern to split your xml per `Parameters` tag and process each other separately and aggregate it later.

Take for example this input:

```
<TransportFeasibilityResponse>
    <Parameters>
        <AvailabilityFlag>true</AvailabilityFlag>
        <SatellitedID>H1B</SatellitedID>
        <BeamID>675</BeamID>
        <TransportName>Earth</TransportName>
    </Parameters>
    <Parameters>
        <AvailabilityFlag>true</AvailabilityFlag>
        <SatellitedID>J34</SatellitedID>
        <BeamID>111</BeamID>
        <TransportName>Jupiter</TransportName>
    </Parameters>
</TransportFeasibilityResponse>
```

A route to process this input could be something like this:

```
from("direct:start")
    .split(xpath("/TransportFeasibilityResponse/Parameters"), new AggregationStrategy() {
        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
            List<String> beamIDs = null;
            if (oldExchange == null) { // first
                beamIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
            } else {
                beamIDs = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            }

            beamIDs.add(newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(beamIDs);
            return newExchange;
        }
    })
        .setBody(xpath("/Parameters/BeamID/text()"))
        .end()
    .log("The final body: ${body}");
```

First, we split the input per `Parameters` tag, and then extract the `BeamID` from it. After that, the `AggregationStrategy` aggregates each message into one, grouping by `BeamID`.

The final message should have the a body like this:

```
675,111
```

The data I put in the body just for an example, but you could set anywhere you want into the `Exchange` you are manipulating inside the `AggregationStrategy`   implementation.

Comment: I think instead of implementing whole aggregator could be better reusing some of already implemented, maybe `AggregationStrategies.flexible(String.class).accumulateInCollection(ArrayList.class)` -- this code was not tested.

Comment: You got a point. But the asker may need a custom implementation. That’s why I show him the entire implementation.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo you responded quite fast. Please see my answer below.